# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars (tflite model)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, tflite

I try to run an tflite-model but always get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "label_image.py", line 133, in 
print('{:08.6f}: {}'.format(float(results[i]), labels[i]))
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

It's the example code from the tensorflow-website with my own model.
It seems lite the model is giving it's results in the wrong format.

Here is the code:

```
# Copyright 2018 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# ==============================================================================
"""label_image for tflite."""

import argparse
import time

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import tflite_runtime.interpreter as tflite
import sys

np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)

def load_labels(filename):
  with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    return [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]


if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument(
      '-i',
      '--image',
      default='Images/sh_17_11_23_s70m_0048.JPG',
      help='image to be classified')
  parser.add_argument(
      '-m',
      '--model_file',
      default='detection-balanced-mcu-2024-02-09T11-36-31.710Z_in-uint8.tflite',
      help='.tflite model to be executed')
  parser.add_argument(
      '-l',
      '--label_file',
      default='labels.txt',
      help='name of file containing labels')
  parser.add_argument(
      '--input_mean',
      default=127.5, type=float,
      help='input_mean')
  parser.add_argument(
      '--input_std',
      default=127.5, type=float,
      help='input standard deviation')
  parser.add_argument(
      '--num_threads', default=None, type=int, help='number of threads')
  parser.add_argument(
      '-e', '--ext_delegate', help='external_delegate_library path')
  parser.add_argument(
      '-o',
      '--ext_delegate_options',
      help='external delegate options, \
            format: "option1: value1; option2: value2"')

  args = parser.parse_args()

  ext_delegate = None
  ext_delegate_options = {}

  # parse extenal delegate options
  if args.ext_delegate_options is not None:
    options = args.ext_delegate_options.split(';')
    for o in options:
      kv = o.split(':')
      if (len(kv) == 2):
        ext_delegate_options[kv[0].strip()] = kv[1].strip()
      else:
        raise RuntimeError('Error parsing delegate option: ' + o)

  # load external delegate
  if args.ext_delegate is not None:
    print('Loading external delegate from {} with args: {}'.format(
        args.ext_delegate, ext_delegate_options))
    ext_delegate = [
        tflite.load_delegate(args.ext_delegate, ext_delegate_options)
    ]

  interpreter = tflite.Interpreter(
      model_path=args.model_file,
      experimental_delegates=ext_delegate,
      num_threads=args.num_threads)
  interpreter.allocate_tensors()

  input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
  output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

  # check the type of the input tensor
  floating_model = input_details[0]['dtype'] == np.float32

  # NxHxWxC, H:1, W:2
  height = input_details[0]['shape'][1]
  width = input_details[0]['shape'][2]
  img = Image.open(args.image).resize((width, height))

  # add N dim
  input_data = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)

  if floating_model:
    input_data = (np.float32(input_data) - args.input_mean) / args.input_std

  interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

  # ignore the 1st invoke
  startTime = time.time()
  interpreter.invoke()
  delta = time.time() - startTime
  print("Warm-up time:", '%.1f' % (delta * 1000), "ms\n")

  startTime = time.time()
  interpreter.invoke()
  delta = time.time() - startTime
  print("Inference time:", '%.1f' % (delta * 1000), "ms\n")

  output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
  results = np.squeeze(output_data)

  top_k = results.argsort()[-5:][::-1]
  labels = load_labels(args.label_file)
  for i in top_k:
    if floating_model:
      print('{:08.6f}: {}'.format(float(results[i]), labels[i]))
    else:
      print('{:08.6f}: {}'.format(float(results[i] / 255.0), labels[i]))
```

For a test I created a tflite-model via the iIQ - Toolkit from NXP. I tried to set the output data type to "int8", "uint8" and "float32" but nothing worked.

Got anyone an idea beside creating a model on the "normal" way?

Comment: Do you know what a 'size 1' array is?  It's taking about shape, not dtype!

Comment: Maybe your results has more than one dimension and resilts[i] gives an array instead of a  scalar value

Comment: Since the error is in the  formatted print, just bypass the pretty formatting for now.  Simply print the array.(s).  It's more important to see and UNDERSTAND the results than to format them in a nice way.

Comment: The last 3 lines of the results array are looking like this: 
"[ 1.72995961e+00 -1.41427350e+00 -1.34660304e+00  4.20616090e-01
  -1.14609189e-01 -3.45648140e-01 -2.40338638e-01]
 [ 1.66960788e+00 -2.88186288e+00 -2.04511452e+00  5.72476208e-01
  -5.88610291e-01 -5.93323588e-01 -1.01087630e+00]
 [ 2.84165931e+00 -2.23241711e+00 -1.94742072e+00  5.45021176e-01
  -8.70254159e-01 -4.33766320e-02  2.74476875e-02]]"